# Constructor to add every instance of a class to a list object

Tags: c++, list, oop, constructor

New to c++ and OOP. I'm trying to figure out lists and iteration, so I've created the following example code. I create a couple Thing objects, but I want to make sure that when a Thing is created, its constructor adds it to a list "things" (inside the lists object) so that I can keep track of every instance of Thing. At the bottom of main() I then iterate through the list of Things. Is there a better way to do this, or could you point out how to do this in my Thing constructor? Thanks!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

class Thing;

class Lists
{
public:
    std::list<Thing> things;
    Lists() {
        std::cout << "List object with list 'things' created" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Thing
{
public:
    int howMuch, pointer;
    Thing(int x, Lists* y)
    {
        howMuch = x;
        y->things.push_back(this);
    }
};

int main()
{

    //create the object that holds the list of things
    Lists lists;

    //make some objects, and pass a pointer of the lists to the constructor
    Thing thingA(123, &lists);
    Thing thingB(456, &lists);

    for (std::list<Thing>::iterator it = lists.things.begin(); it != lists.things.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << "test" << it->howMuch << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `static std::list<Thing> things;`, you won't need to pass object pointer.

Comment: could have a `void addThing(int howMuch);` function in your List

Comment: Did you mean `std::list<Thing*> things;` instead of `std::list<Thing> things;`? Notice the added `*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store created items inside the Thing class itself using a static field _things:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

class Thing
{
    static std::list<Thing> _things;

public:
    int howMuch, pointer;
    Thing(int x) : howMuch(x)
    {
        _things.push_back(*this);
    }

    static std::list<Thing> getAllThings()
    {
        return _things;
    }
};


std::list<Thing> Thing::_things;

int main()
{
    Thing thingA(123);
    Thing thingB(456);

    auto allThings = Thing::getAllThings();

    for (auto it = allThings.begin(); it != allThings.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << "test " << it->howMuch << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This and the original example will both encounter big problems as soon as any Thing is destroyed. It only works for the simplest scenarios.

Comment: @François Andrieux, for the `Thing` as it is defined currently I don't see how we can encounter problems. I suppose by problems you meant using an object after it has been destroyed. But the `Thing` does not contain any fields which require ownership transfer. Depending on how we want to change the `Thing` and how to track instances of it we can either make special copies of `Thing`s or remove `Thing`s which has been destroyed from the list.

Comment: @Max, thanks! @Francois, is your solution to these "big problems" resolved by using the pointer `<Thing*>` that you mention in your previous comment?

Comment: why use auto? can't you just use Thing::_things? it is already defined

Comment: @schanti schul. I don't understand your question. `auto` is used for type deduction, so that you don't have to type the full class name. You cannot replace `auto` with `Thing::_things` if that's what you're asking. For one thing, `auto` is a substitute for type name while `Thing::_things` is not a type, but a class field. Secondly,  Thing::_things is a private field, which is not accessible from outside of the class's scope.

Comment: @Max Last question, can I have std::list<Thing> Thing::_things definition in .h file ? Is it some sort of singleton?

Comment: Yes, it is a sort of singleton. It's a static field of a class. You should not place `std::list<Thing> Thing::_things;` in a header file, it has to be in a cpp file. Or you can instead use `inline static` (starting from C++17).

Answer (score 2):

The original example and the example in answer 1 encounter problems as soon as any Thing is destroyed (as François Andrieux mentioned), even if you use a pointer to Thing in the list. If you use a Thing in a subroutine as a local variable, the Thing is destroyed at the end of this function, but is still in the list. To solve this problem, you have to remove the Thing from the list in the destructor of Thing. But if you do so, you get a problem, when Thing is a global object. You have two global objects - the list and the Thing. It is not clear, which is destroyed first, so you can end up whith an access violation, which is difficult to debug, because it happens after exit().

Here is my proposal:

```
    template<class T>
    class InstanceIterator{ // Iterator for an InstanceList
    public:
        InstanceIterator(T*pT)
            : pt(pT)
        {}
        T& operator*(){ return *pt; }
        T* operator->(){ return pt; }
        InstanceIterator operator++(){
            pt=pt->instanceList.pNext;
            return *this;
        }
        int operator!=(const InstanceIterator<T>& i){ return i.pt!=pt; }
    private:
        T*pt;
    };

    template<class T>
    class InstanceList{
    // this class means not the whole list, but only the element (pNext)
    // which is inserted into the object you want to have in a list.
    // there is no explizite list, every instance class T has a part of the list
    public:
        InstanceList(){};
        void insert(T* pt){ // gets the this-pointer of the surrounding class
            pNext=pFirst; 
            pFirst=pt;
        }
        ~InstanceList();
        static InstanceIterator<T> begin(){ return pFirst; }
        static InstanceIterator<T> end(){ return 0; }
        static bool empty(){ return pFirst==0; }
    private:
        InstanceList(const InstanceList&);// no copy constructor
        void operator=(const InstanceList&);// no assignment 
        static T* pFirst;
        T* pNext;
        friend class InstanceIterator<T>;
    };

    template<class T>
    InstanceList<T>::~InstanceList(){
        T**ppInst=&pFirst;
        // search for myself
        while(&((*ppInst)->instanceList)!=this) { // its me?
            if(0==(*ppInst)) {
                return; // emergency exit
            }
            ppInst=&((*ppInst)->instanceList.pNext); // the next please
        }
        // and remove me from the list
        (*ppInst)=pNext;
    }

    template<class T>
    T* InstanceList<T>::pFirst=0; 

    // how to use and test the above template:
    // (uses 3 objects: one is global, one is local, 
    // and one is deleted before going through the list)
    class InstanceTest { // example class, the instances of this class are listed
    public:
        InstanceTest(int i)
            : i(i)
        {
            instanceList.insert(this); // dont forget this line
        }
        InstanceList<InstanceTest> instanceList; // must have this line with exact this name
        int i;
    };

    InstanceTest t1(1); // a global object

    int main() {
        std::cout << "testing InstanceIterator";
        InstanceTest t2(2); // a local object
        InstanceTest* pt3 = new InstanceTest(3); // will be deleted later
        int sum(0);
        for(InstanceIterator<InstanceTest> it= InstanceList<InstanceTest>::begin(); it!= InstanceList<InstanceTest>::end();++it){
            sum += it->i;
        }
        int testFailed(0);
        if (sum != 6) testFailed++;
        delete pt3;
        sum = 0;
        for (InstanceIterator<InstanceTest> it = InstanceList<InstanceTest>::begin(); it != InstanceList<InstanceTest>::end(); ++it) {
            sum += it->i;
        }
        if (sum != 3) testFailed++;
        if (testFailed) {
            std::cout << "... FAILED !!!\n";
        }
        else std::cout << "... OK\n";
        return testFailed;
    }
```

Comment: Would like to know if there is a safe way to do it by inheritance getting added to some list automatically?